# `No such file or directory:` ruff. but file exists

Tags: files, filesystems, nixos, nix

I am using `nixOS` and I have a [flake.nix](https://pastebin.com/552UmR5Q). I use `pre-commit` to run `ruff`.

my pre-commit config:

```
-   repo: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-pre-commit
    rev: v0.3.4
    hooks:
    -   id: ruff
        alias: autoformat
        args: [--fix]
```

Now when committing `.py` files I get this error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/{username}/.cache/pre-commit/repoo90awvpu/py_env-python3.11/bin/ruff'
```

But the file exists! I checked it. My `ls` command (with a full path) gives me:

```
.rwxr-xr-x 23M {username} 28 Mär 00:26 /home/{username}/.cache/pre-commit/repoo90awvpu/py_env-python3.11/bin/ruff
```

file outputs:

```
> file ruff
ruff: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=5703233b90c05154cbdd5c3f44975b02579aad23, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
```

Does anyone know why I get the error, that my file does not exists, when it actually exists and is executable.

Comment: In what directory were you when you ran the `ls` command? Try the `ls` with the full pathname as given in the error message from the commit.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant see my edit please. I posted the output of `ls` with the full pathname.

Comment: Does `{username}` contain any unusual characters, or is any part of that path a symlink?

Comment: @JohnGordon No, my username is `xunil`. There is no symlink.

Comment: What is the output of `file -L /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am not having a `lib64` folder.

Comment: Okay with this hint I figured out my problem https://github.com/Mic92/nix-ld